# Kotlin - Mapstruct - @AfterMapping can only be applied to an implemented class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mapstruct

I am currently working on a mapstruct mapping on Kotlin, which has some relationship that uses Spring boot repository and services to get the object for further processing. However, I was not able to implement `@AfterMapping`.

```kotlin
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface Objectmapper {

  @Mappings(
    Mapping(source = "aCode", target = "a.code"),
    Mapping(source = "bCode", target = "b.code")
  )
  fun convertFormDtoToEntity(
    dto: ObjectFormDto,
    @Context aRepo: ARepository,
    @Context bService: BService
  ): Object

  @AfterMapping
  fun afterMappingFormDtoToEntity(
    dto: ObjectFormDto,
    @Context aRepo: ARepository,
    @Context bService: BService,
    @MappingTarget object: Object
  ){
    object.a = aRepo.findByA(object.a.code)
    object.b = bService.getB(object.b.code)
  }
}
```

My goal is to implement the `afterMappingFormDtoToEntity()` after the mapping on `convertFormToEntity()` is done, but I was not able to finish the `kaptKotlin` job and returned the error

```
error: @AfterMapping can only be applied to an implemented class
    public abstract void afterMappingFormDtoToEntity(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()...
```

My current mapstruct version is "1.5.2.Final", with kapt version "1.6.10", the following `kapt` settings in `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg("mapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy", "IGNORE")
    }
    keepJavacAnnotationProcessors = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solve by changing the mapper type

from `interface Objectmapper` to `abstract class ObjectMapper` and convert all the methods to abstract except the `@AfterMapping` method

The detail is written in my Medium blog post:
https://3lexw.medium.com/how-to-use-mapstruct-in-kotlin-spring-with-injection-spring-services-and-repositories-5c3f468ee261

Answer (score 0):

Implemented methods in Kotlin interfaces are not marked as implemented. Therefore MapStruct thinks that the method is abstract and needs to be implemented.

In order for things to work you'll need to annotate the method with `@JvmDefault`